# Separable Differential Equation dy/dt = 6y

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The question is as follows:

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=6y$$

$$y(9)=5$$

I tried rearranging the equation to $\frac{dy}{6y} = dt$ and integrating both sides to get $(1/6)\ln|y| + C = t$. After that I tried plugging in the $9$ for $y$ and $5$ for $t$ and solving but I can't quite seem to get it.

Comment: Sorry I can't include the picture, don't have enough reputation..

Comment: Hello David and welcome to the site!  We use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type out our math.  Cheers! $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac 16\ln|y| = t+C$
I would be inclined to not solve for C at this time.

You could say

$\frac 16\ln|5| = 9+C\\
C = \frac 16\ln|5| - 9$

But I think that makes for more work in the long run

$\frac 16\ln|y| = t+C\\
\ln|y| = 6t+C$

Notice that $C$ just stays $C.$  $6C, C,$ it is just an arbitrary constant.

$y = e^{6t+C}\\
y=e^Ce^{6t}\\
y = C e^{6t}$

I did it again!
And once you have done these for a week, you will drop the intermediate steps and go:

$\frac 16\ln|y| = t+C\\
y = C e^{6t}$

We have to find C now.

$y(9) = 5\\
5 = C e^{54}\\
C = 5e^{-54}\\
y = 5e^{-54}e^{6t}$

or

$y = 5e^{6t-54}$

Answer (score 1):

You should plug in 9 for $t$ and 5 for $y$.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually asked a question: what are you trying to do?  Assuming it is to solve the IVP, your next step is to find $C$. From your own formula, you have:
$$
C = t - \ln |y| /6.
$$
If $t = 5$ and $y(5) = 9,$ then
$$
C = 5 - (\ln 9)/6.
$$
Now solve your formula for $y$, and you are done.